# Error message when linking an app to QBO

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

When a client clicks on our QBO connect link, they get redirected to log into QB, which the client does and they get the following error message:

```
Oops! An error has occurred. 
Please close this window and try again. 

Error Code: invalid_database 
Message: The application has already been subscribed to by another user for this company
```

What could be causing the message?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is:

> The application has already been subscribed to by another user for
>   this company

Another QuickBooks user has already subscribed (connected) to the app. Why are you allowing/trying to reconnect if another user has already connected?

Comment: the issue is that I removed the connection in QBO and on the 3rd party app. It works with my other QBO clients except this one.